# How do I prevent the password being checked to enable the "next" button if an invalid login is entered prior to the if statement?

Tags: java, security, netbeans, passwords

I'm designing a program where you are registering for an organization. To reach the registration page however, you first need to login using another member's access key.

I have put in a switch statement assigning different passwords to different user names. I have then used an if statement to check if the password is correct according to the member entered and if not, to display a message indicating such. This works perfectly fine, however, if you input a member's name that isn't of the three I've hardcoded for, the code allows you to completely bypass the password field, basically making the security measures useless.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this, I would really appreciate it. I'm assuming it's something simple but I am extremely new to coding, particularly the GUI and just can't figure it out.

I'm using NetBeans GUI builder.

Thank you!

[Image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvHsu.png)

Comment: It is greatly preferred that you post your code in the question rather than an image.

Comment: That said, you have a case in your switch statement that detects the user is unknown and displays a message to the user. What do you want to happen after than dialog is displayed?  As it is the code will just keep executing with the next statement.

Comment: Another point, you never want to store plain text passwords. Ever. If this is just a toy application, fine. If you intend to use this for real you need to read up on how to manage sensitive info like this - such as using cryptographic hashes.

Comment: Thank you for responding @crig I'm not yet able to post my code in the question as I only just joined this platform (unless I'm missing a setting) but will do so as soon as I'm able to. After that dialog is displayed, I don't want the if statement t be processed but rather have for the user to have to reenter the member name entirely. I attempted placing the if statement nested into the switch statement but thishowever gave me error codes

Comment: Thank you for the advice on passwords! This is for a school project and we were told to hardcode for the password to allow the marker to easily access but I really appreciate that advice for future projects.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change it slightly where that error no longer occurs. It is not completely perfect according to my intentions however this works for my needed functions.

If you have any further suggestions on how to improve this even more, I would still really appreciate it.

Thank you for all the assistance!

[Adjusted code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui54a.png)
(I also changed the messages to buttons for aesthetic purposes)

Comment: Please don't [include code as picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Can you edit your question to copy/paste it ?